# How can I make a one neuron neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, linear-regression, backpropagation, one-hot-encoding

I want to make a one neuron function like w1*x1+w2*x2+w3*x3+b1
My training input is

```
                    [1, 0, 0], 
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1],
                    [1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1],
                    [2, 0, 0]
```

And training output is :

```
[1,2,0,1,0,2,3]
```

I tried to make a code with one hot encoding but i failed. I am new to AI coding and I don't want to use any AI libraries such as Pytorch and Tensorflow or scikitlearn. This problem was troubling me for 2 weeks and I also tried different codes which didnt work. Here is an example code which I know it is wrong but It may give you an insight.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 /(1+np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return x*(1-x)

training_inputs = np.array([
                    [1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1],
                    [1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1],
                    [2, 0, 0]
                ])

training_outputs = np.array([[1,2,0,1,0,2,3]]).T

np.random.seed(1)

synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random.random((3,1))-1
print('Random starting synaptic weights: ')
print(synaptic_weights)

for iteration in range(2000):

    input_layer = training_inputs

    outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights))

    error = training_outputs - outputs

    adjustments = error * sigmoid_derivative(outputs)

    synaptic_weights += np.dot(input_layer.T,adjustments)

print('Synaptic Weights After Training: ')
print(synaptic_weights)

print('Outputs after training: ')
print(outputs)
```

I want it to output results like [0,1,0,0] meaning 1 as one hot encoded. Which I dont know how to.

Comment: This is not a coding problem, you need to understand the basics of neural networks first, before attempting to code one from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can assume this is a classification problem seeing you using sigmoid.

However, you've got 4 classes, so we'll need to use its multiclass generalization, the softmax function.

As you properly noticed, we'll need to use one-hot encoding for the target: your predictions should be the same shape as `training_outputs`. It can be done trivially `using np.eye()`.

Next, you mention `b` in the linear equation, so you'll have to add a bias column to the `training_inputs` (all ones).

As a result, the weights will become a 4x4 matrix (4 features including bias and 4 classes).

Finally, the learning rate might be needed to be reduced a bit.

No additional derivatives need to be calculated: the derivative of log loss w.r.t. weights is still proportional to `X * error`.

This could probably be improved further if we scaled the training data.

Worth noting multiclass classification is not quite one neuron but rather one neuron per class.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.special import softmax

training_inputs = np.array([
                    [1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1],
                    [1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1],
                    [2, 0, 0]
                ])

# Adding bias
training_inputs = np.hstack([training_inputs, np.ones((training_inputs.shape[0], 1))])

training_outputs = np.array([1,2,0,1,0,2,3])
# One-hot encoding
training_outputs = np.eye(4)[training_outputs]

np.random.seed(1)

synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random.random((4,4))-1
print('Random starting synaptic weights: ')
print(synaptic_weights)

for iteration in range(2000):

    input_layer = training_inputs

    # Softmax here
    outputs = softmax(np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights), axis=1)

    error = training_outputs - outputs
    
    synaptic_weights += np.dot(input_layer.T,error) * 0.1 # learning rate

print('Synaptic Weights After Training: ')
print(synaptic_weights)

print('Outputs after training (one-hot): ')
print(np.round(outputs))

print('Outputs after training: ')
print(np.argmax(outputs, axis=1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was stuck at this problem. Your help meant a lot for me.